# How to read full disk once and monitor progress/speed on old Linux?

Tags: linux, knoppix

I have an old PC here and I want to check the HDD. I want to read it once completely into `/dev/null`. While doing this I want to see the speed.

Because the PC is old I couldn't boot a recent Debian version.

But I got Knoppix running. There is a lot of stuff on the CD but unfortunately `dd` does not support the `status=progress` option (because it's old) and `pv` is not installed. Any ideas?

Knoppix version is 3.2.

Comment: Try sending signal `USR1` to the `dd` process: `kill -USR1 $PID`

Comment: @Panki Yes that works.

Comment: Lots of Debian and other distros archives on the net: you could simply download a dd/pv binary and run it. Also, if I remember correctly Knoppix contains GCC which allows to compile applications.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Of course. But sending signal USR1 to dd is much easier.

Comment: `pv -petrab ` looks/works so much nicer :-)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It's not that easy. When I download a binary for pv it won't run because Knoppix is too old (libraries + kernel). And when I download the source I can't compile it because my system is too old. I'd have to find a version which runs on Knoppix 3.2 and that is not an easy task.

Comment: If your version of Knoppix has `badblocks` you might find that more useful to check your HDD.